# Can I make seurat object from GSE121861?

Tags: r, geo, seurat

I have a question about data export from GEO to seurat object.

I want to make GSE121861 dataset to seurat object file.
(https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE121861)

Usually I make seurat object by 3 files (barcodes, features, matrix)
-> dataX.data <- Read10X(data.dir = "E:/Mouse_Singlecell_Public/eee")

but GSE121861 have only (coulmn, expression, row data) form.

So I want to ask how can I transform GSE121861 dataset to seurat object?

Thankyou.

Comment: What makes you block ? You should be able to convert the expression matrix to Seurat object

Comment: @Basti Thank you for your answer, how can I convert those files to expression matrix of Seurat? Would you inform to me?

Comment: Download the expression matrix and use CreateSeuratObject(), but it seems this is not raw counts so you should be careful on how you pfurther proceed with this dataset : https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/5115/seurat-with-normalized-count-matrix